# May I have a license to use an image from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I've made a copy of Stack Overflow's upload image modal. Like this:

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow's upload modal except the text is in a different language. The artwork in the center, an upload cloud with three different image icons above it, has been circled in red.]

The warning message at the top is translated like this:

> Make sure that the image you upload is valid and compatible with community policy. If you are using an image that you are not the author, please adding the source.

The difference is I'm using this modal with dropzonejs.

[image: The same screenshot as above except there is a different image in place of the circled artwork.]

My question is: Can I have a license to use that upload icon (SVG) circled in red in the first image? I have a line *Powered by StackOverflow* at the bottom.

Comment: Why are you literally copying Stack Overflow's design? You're not making a clone, are you?

Comment: @Cerbrus I like this design and I want to use it for my website. Since I've used an icon of StackOverflow, I cannot publish it until StackOverflow agrees

Comment: Pretty much the situation I used to be in where I paid for my CDs and then someone else wanted to mooch a free copy off of me. How about: no.

Comment: @Gimby I'm sorry but I didn't say anything about `free` here.

Comment: @AlanWalker Fair enough but if you're willing to pay then you can commission an icon for yourself

Comment: How is your uploader "Powered by StackOverflow" exactly? I think the phrase you are looking for is "Copied from StackOverflow".

Comment: @Gimby That's how we have a lot of KFC (Kentucky Fried Chicken) restaurants in many countries.

Comment: The site's name is Stack Overflow (with a space between Stack and Overflow, both of which have their initial letters capitalized).

Comment: LMAO this is called reinventing the wheel while pirating a thing,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [trademark guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) for Stack Exchange.

You'll be better served rolling your own icons, or using one of [the many icons available online with permisive licenses](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20web%20icons&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b).

No need to rip off Stack Exchange, no matter how much you love the network. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've just read and found a line: `Do not copy the look and feel of our products.` ^^!